# How can I include the main line ship date in line item results for a sales order saved search?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to create a Saved Search that can be used to break down on time shipments by item type. However, I've noticed that {shipdate} isn't included in the results for the line items on sales orders.

[Here is an example search where the "Inventory Item" line does not have ship date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5DU.png)

I've tried using a formula field and variations of {*.shipdate} and {mainline.shipdate}, but they only produce errors; {mainline.shipdate} produces "Field not found" and {*.shipdate} produces "Invalid Expression." I do not have the same problem with {actualshipdate} as this date is displayed on line item results when included.

How do I access this main line dimension on line item results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd that your NetSuite isn't returning the mainline ship date on every line. It does for me, so perhaps there is a setting somewhere.

Apart from finding a setting, the simplest way to return the Ship Date on every line is with an analytic function:

```
MIN/*_*/({shipdate}) OVER (PARTITION BY {internalid})
```

[image: NetSuite Search Columns]

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Great answer, just a nitpick on the screenshot, it's actually a SQL comment not JS :-)

Answer (score 2):

Nathan's answer made me want to take another look at this, as I was also surprised that NetSuite was not returning the Ship Date field with each line.  I found that having Demand Planning enabled affects how NetSuite displays the Ship Date.

From SuiteAnswers:

> If the Demand Planning Feature is enabled, values for the Date Shipped column in the Report will be sourced from the 'Expected Ship Date' column on the line item level of the Sales Order. Thus, using Ship Date on the report will return a null value if Demand Planning Feature is enabled.

So turning demand planning on means line Ship Date = null, demand planning off means line Ship Date = head Ship Date (in saved search).

Probably not really of any practical help, but good to know the underlying reason.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make a custom column (line) field and copy the header ship date field to each line using a workflow or script (could be scheduled or triggered on the before submit event).

Another way to work around it could be to use the new SuiteAnalytics workbook feature, if you don't have other things depending on this to be a saved search.

Comment: The idea seems to be to leverage the email automation; using a SuiteAnalytics portlet would have to be a sell - although I prefer it coming from a BI background, not many people here share my enthusiasm. I'm a bit of a newb with scripting, could you show an example? And can this be set while also applying the filter main line = no?