# Netsuite field blank in reports and saved searches for Transfer Orders

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to build a report that shows me open (Pending Fulfilment) Transfer Orders by item. Here is what I would like to see:

- To Location
- Item Name
- Document Number
- Ship date

When I build an item saved search I can get everything listed above except the Ship Date is blank. The field exists under Transaction Fields>Ship Date and I have it in my results tab but when I preview the search the column is empty, no results return even though the Date is not blank when I look up individual records.

When I build a Transaction saved search with the To Location, Item>Name, Document Number, Ship Date where Type=Transfer Order, the Item>Name column is empty in the preview/results but the Ship Date and other fields have info.

Does anyone have any suggestions? current solution is 2 searches and then combining them later which is a pain. I have tried the same things with reports instead of saved searches and get the same issue.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: 
Example of what I'm getting with Main Line = Either on Transaction Search

DOCUMENT NUMBER       NAME            SHIP DATE

```
TO302                             05/04/2020
TO302            ITEM3   
TO302            ITEM4   
TO302            ITEM5   
TO302            ITEM6   
TO302            ITEM7   
TO302            ITEM8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What filters are you setting in the criteria tab?  When you create an Item saved search, it pulls in results from the transaction item lines, but not the main line.  I suspect when you make the transaction search you're setting the Main Line filter to Yes which would exclude the Item Lines.

Ship Date field (usually in the Shipping tab) is a header field, which is only returned in the Main Line results.  If you want to see results returned for that field for the Item Lines, you need to enable Demand Planning (Setup > Company > Enable Features > Items & Inventory > Demand Planning).  The Ship Date field will then return the line field "Expected Ship Date" with Item lines in a saved search.  It will continue to return the header field "Ship Date" with any main lines returned.

You can see documentation for this in SuiteAnswers ID: 29429.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The criteria on the transaction search is Type=Transfer Order and Status=Pending Fulfillment. The columns in my report are: Document Number, Item>Name, Ship Date. When I put Main Line= Either I get mixed results where the first line returns data in the Document number and Ship Date columns, and then I get a row per item in the transfer order that has the document number & item name but the Ship Date field is blank. I don't see any Expected Ship Date field, where would I find this?

Comment: Expected Ship Date is not a separate entry in the saved search results selection list.  When you select Ship Date in the search Results tab, the saved search will return the Ship Date field you already identified with Main Line results, and it will return Expected Ship Date with all Item Line results.  However, you have to have Demand Planning turned on (as above) for Expected Ship Date to have any values.  Hope this clarifies,

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my last response that we do have Demand Planning turned on and I'm still getting blank ship dates at the item line level. It is only populating at the main line level.

Comment: Try populating the Expected Ship Date of the transfer order(s) item lines with some value, and see if that comes through to the search results.  It should.  If that field is blank the result will be blank, of course.  Going forward, you might need some automated method to populate the Expected Ship Date on each line.  You could use a workflow or script to copy the value from the header Ship Date to each line if that meets your business rules.  This is just a simple suggestion though, and may not be the best way.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702354/how-can-i-include-the-main-line-ship-date-in-line-item-results-for-a-sales-order/58716041#58716041).  I answered it but had forgotten about it...Nathans answer there might help too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The date formula on the other thread did the trick for me!